# PHP add elements to array using foreach()

Tags: php, arrays

How to add elements to the array using the foreach loop?

```
    $list = [
        ['User-ID', 'Payout-ID', 'Amount', 'Withdraw address', 'Date'],
    ];

    //generate CSV
    foreach ($open_payouts as $open_payout) {
        $list .= [
            (string)$open_payout->user_id,
            (string)$open_payout->id,
            (string)number_format($open_payout->amount / 100000000, 8, '.', ''),
            (string)$open_payout->user->withdraw_address,
            (string)$open_payout->created_at,
        ];
    }

    $fp = fopen(app_path() . '/CSV/file.csv', 'w');
    //write whole list
    foreach ($list as $fields) {
        fputcsv($fp, $fields);
    }
```

It seems like my problem is located at `$list .=`. How to insert another array into this array, so I can generate a .CSV file from the arrays?

Comment: `$list[] = [x, y, z, ...];` which is shorthand for [`array_push()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)

Comment: To add elements to an array, its `$list[] =`. Using `$list .=` is for *string* concating.

Answer (score 1):

`.=` is used to concatenate strings - not arrays.

You simply need to use;

```
$list[] = [
        (string)$open_payout->user_id,
        (string)$open_payout->id,
        (string)number_format($open_payout->amount / 100000000, 8, '.', ''),
        (string)$open_payout->user->withdraw_address,
        (string)$open_payout->created_at,
    ];
```

That will add your new array onto the end of your `$list` array.

You could also use [`array_push()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php);

```
array_push($list, [
    (string)$open_payout->user_id,
    (string)$open_payout->id,
    (string)number_format($open_payout->amount / 100000000, 8, '.', ''),
    (string)$open_payout->user->withdraw_address,
    (string)$open_payout->created_at,
]);
```